# Seeking low-resolution DEM of California?

Tags: data, dem, united-states

I'm trying to create a 3D model of California (which I'll manipulate in Blender) at a fairly low resolution — just enough for large features (like Mt. Tamalpais, Coronado, etc.) to be legible.  Wherever I look, I find DEM's at much higher-resolution that would require a lot of stitching together and would likely tax my computer's capabilities.  Any ideas?  A bonus would be a DEM including Baja California too, but I realize most US sources won't have that data.

Comment: Sounds like getting the resolution I'm looking for (~100m) is known to be difficult: "The only problem with these data is when we need to make some analysis in a regional scale." http://carlosgrohmann.com/regional-scale-analysis-of-dems-resample-and-derive-or-derive-and-resample-paper-review/

Answer (score 1):

Trying Google reveals lots of free and open datasets out there.
Here's one from [NOAA](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/globe.html) at 1KM resolution. 
You can clip the global/continental dataset to your required area with any basic GIS software

Comment: Thanks, it's the number of datasets that makes this so hard.  I hadn't seen that one, but looks like it's at the other extreme — this is too rough a rendering of the SF Bay Area: http://imgur.com/evwNZBT